# Is it correct to say "it accounts the" in place of "taking into consideration"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, nouns

Example:

> It accounts the total size of data...
> It accounts the total time required to complete job X...

In place of:

> taking into consideration the total size of data...
> taking into consideration the total time required to complete job X...

Comment: What do you find dictionaries say about the verbal usage of account? I've found in [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account), for instance, that the transitive verb account is typically used in [ V + obj + noun/adj ] constructions: **account** verb  [formal] {[V] + [obj] + [noun/adj]}  ...
to think of someone or something in the stated way:
_She was accounted a genius by all who knew her work. [They accounted/considered her a genius.]_

Answer (score 1):

No. Phrases such as: "account **for**", "take into account" or "take account of" should be used instead.

From Merriam Webster:

> **account for (something)**
>
> (4) *US*: to think about (something) before doing something: to take (something) into consideration

> **take account of**
> <sub>idiomatic phrase</sub>
>
> variants: *or* **take into account**
>
> : to give attention or consideration to (something)

---

> *Accounting for* the total size of data...
> *Accounting for* the total time required to complete job X...
>
> *Taking into account* the total size of data...
> *Taking into account* the total time required to complete job X...
>
> *Taking account of* the total size of data...
> *Taking account of* the total time required to complete job X...

Comment: Thanks. If let's say, we are actually counting numbers in the above two phrases, will "it accounts for" sound wrong, because the emphasis is on "already counting within this"?

Comment: @ShubhamDeshmukh: You mean "*Counting the total size of data...*"? Then yes, "it accounts for" is wrong.